# Optimizing the query in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a table (doc(varchar), sentenceId(int), bow(varchar[])). In the bow column I import bag of words. In total there are 4623 rows. Table (nlptable) looks like(for 10 vectors):

```
doc    | sentenceId | bow  
-------------------------------------------
corpus |      1     | {1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1}  
corpus |      2     | {0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0}
```

The query I run (compare bag of words representation of two sentences):

```
select a.doc, a.sentenceid, b.doc, b.sentenceid, 
cardinality(array(select unnest(array_positions(a.bow, '1')) intersect select unnest(array_positions(b.bow, '1'))))::float / cardinality(a.bow)::float
from 
  nlptable a, nlptable b
where 
  a.sentenceid < b.sentenceid;
```

The problem is that for 10 vectors (10 most common words) the execution time is about 3 minutes, for 100 vectors about 25 minutes and for 500 vectors 80 minutes. I have to make calculation for 10,000 most common words, which will possibly take 1 day. The query is too slow and I want to optimize it, but now idea how. Is there an option to use some boolean type instead of varchar[] to deacrease size of data? I also did explain analyze:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..25486703.85 rows=7124043 width=232) (actual time=2.028..1126759.206 rows=10683753 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (a.sentenceid < b.sentenceid)
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 10688376
   ->  Seq Scan on nlpdata a  (cost=0.00..214.23 rows=4623 width=116) (actual time=0.261..9.486 rows=4623 loops=1)
   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..237.35 rows=4623 width=116) (actual time=0.001..3.509 rows=4623 loops=4623)
         ->  Seq Scan on nlpdata b  (cost=0.00..214.23 rows=4623 width=116) (actual time=0.207..6.968 rows=4623 loops=1)
   SubPlan 1
         ->  HashSetOp Intersect  (cost=0.00..3.52 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.079..0.081 rows=2 loops=10683753)
           ->  Append  (cost=0.00..3.02 rows=200 width=0) (actual time=0.017..0.062 rows=8 loops=10683753)
             ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.00..1.51 rows=100 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.025 rows=4 loops=10683753)
                   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.51 rows=100 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.018 rows=4 loops=10683753)
```

I am relatively new to postgres, so have no idea about optimization. I also heard that arrays in postgres are heavy to deal with. Because of this I searched alternative ways to store bag of words in table, but can not find functionality other than in arrays.

Comment: I wonder if using a junction table with appropriate indexes would boost performance.

Comment: Can you describe tokenizedsentence column with examples? does bow have the same length?

Comment: Can you create a test data example to better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Edit: Instead of tokenizedsentence I should have written "bow", just shortened the name. I am running another query, when I finish I will post exact output.